# What does a double red circle mean in rxgraph

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes nodes appear in rxgraph as a double red circle instead of a black oval (see image below). What does the double  red circle mean? The nodes seem to be working fine, ie they are sending and recieving data on topics.

[image description http://www.pitchless.org/mark/rxgraph-double-red-circle.png](http://www.pitchless.org/mark/rxgraph-double-red-circle.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12691/what-does-a-double-red-circle-mean-in-rxgraph/) by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

double red circle means that the Master reports the node exists, but rxgraph cannot talk to that node.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-01-19**:
I just can attest my rxgraph (11.10 electric) gets out of sync alot, e.g. if I remap a node's topic and restart it, rxgraph shows a connection to both topics.

**Comment by [markpitchless](https://answers.ros.org/users/1668/markpitchless/) on 2012-01-19**:
I do get other nodes in rxgraph that it says it can't connect to (in the info panel on the right) that don't get the red circle. Just noticed that the port number for node given in the rxgraph error is different to the port that rosnode info gives. Looks like rxgraph gets out of sync.